# Opening strategies in Chess 960 (Fisher Random Chess)

Tags: chess, openings, variants

I had a go at Chess 960 the other day, but whereas I thought I might do better against the computer as it didn't have an opening book, in fact the opposite happened as it quickly found holes in my position. Are there any good opening strategies? Is it best to try to massage your position into classical chess positions or to try to build a fortress around the castled king?

Comment: The value of castling would seem to go down sharply if the king starts somewhere other than mid-board.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Silman's book *How to reassess your chess*, it's said that it's the position which tell us what moves we have to play. I guess in 960 chess, more than in classical chess, the most important move is the first (maybe it would be better to take more time before playing it, except in a fast game).

Even if the initial position are symmetrical, Whites have an advantage which may be great in function of the initial position. So first look at the weaknesses of the opponent's and yours position (for example, in the classical position, f7 (respectively f2) is weak), if you bishops (which are necessary in square of different colors) already attack a weak square after moving a pawn, but overall if your king is safe. If there is a square which is only protected by the king, maybe it would be better to defend it quickly, or if you have Whites, try to attack it or at least put pressure on the Blacks.

Answer (score 3):

I am not an expert at 960 Chess, but the same basic rules apply: develop your pieces, take control of the center, and bring your king to safety as quickly as possible.

Comment: how do you know they apply, you just say so? Give some example games or arguments. Also, it's 960 not 360.

Comment: The standard arguments apply as in classic chess. Developed pieces and control of the center give you influence over more squares on the board and more legal moves. Getting your king to safety speaks for itself.

Comment: I agree with that, but sometimes even if there is an argument, the empirical route could demonstrate to say something different. I believe what you say, but it is needed better more stronger proofs.

Answer (score 0):

Look where his Rooks are, and see if they're unprotected.  Often they are.  So aim to get your Bishops attacking the pawn, then that would get his Rook.